# Magento 2 : Set different price on different store view and render in admin product form

Tags: magento-2.1, price, product-attribute, store-view, adminform

I am working on an extension in which I need to create different prices based on the different store view. I have created own table in which I am saving store view id and product id on event catalog_product_save_after.

I want to join this table with a product price table in the data provider of product form in admin. I tried with different tricks, but I failed. I need to show the price per store view. Could anyone help me to achieve this? Help will be appreciated

Thank You

[image]

Comment: Did you try to change price with diffrent store view??

Comment: Have you used default price attribute or you created new attribute for your custom extenison?

Comment: yep, i tried, default magento set price on base of website and i tried to change price with store view wise with code too @jigs parmar

Comment: I am using default price attribute. i have edited it in my install script. i have changed it's scope from global to store view @DhirenVasoya

Comment: did you code for that?? or directly use magneto standard to change price for diffrant store

Comment: Yep,  i have code for that and i got success in front but unfortunate in backend with data provider in ui form

Comment: no need to create any attribute its done by default magento

Comment: i haven't created any attribute, i said i edited default attribute to change it's scope @jigsparmar

Comment: why you change scope??

Comment: you change scope thats why its not work

Comment: Because i need it store view wise so it cannot be global anymore @jigsparmar

Comment: sachu bol nay ne gyo cho office??

Comment: i am in office buddy @jigsparmar, i am developing extension of product pricing on store view

Comment: Have you check your requirement in default magento? I think it magento default functionlity to set price of product based on diffrent store. And it working fine.

Comment: Yes, i already check. We can set price either website wise or global in Magento 2. Default Magento2  is not providing store view wise pricing. @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Its Work Bro. I check it

Comment: check in fresh magneto2.

Comment: It doesn't work. If it works then nobody needs this extension anymore.

You will get same price in all store view in same website @jigsparmar

It will change the price only on store view which is in different website try it.

Comment: I recently try to set product price based on store view from admin I am getting product price based on store view its working in my case. Something is wrong in your default *magento2*.

Comment: everyone get's price based on store view so you need to check it one more time.

Comment: Well,  From Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price and check the price scope dropdown: it gives two option either global or website. Secondly, Check default price attribute scope, it will be global. thirdly save price in seocnd storeview and check price in first store view it will be same.
@NewBeeInMagento

Comment: @jigsparmar without this extension it is not possible https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multiple-store-view-pricing-for-magento-2.html

Comment: Check this one http://prntscr.com/gmljto and http://prntscr.com/gmllww

Comment: Well, let me check again @NewBeeInMagento i hope you must be right :) it will take pain of head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer the answer of above question by printing events in \vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php

On event catalog_product_edit_action call your own observer just fetch price data for particular store view and  set that price like this

```
  $observer->getProduct()->setPrice(50);
```

that's it, here static price 50 is set in admin product edit form.